# Unable to read all the cell values in a row when using Apache POI library

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am facing a problem while iterating all the cells in a row, I am able to read first 4 cells properly rest all coming as null. Any help appreciated
//Below is the code I am using

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
    int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {
      Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
      String name = sheet.getSheetName();
      if (name.equals(sheetName)) {
        Iterator<Row> rowItr = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowItr.hasNext()) {
          Row eachRow = rowItr.next();
          QuestionObjBuilder builder = new QuestionObjBuilder();
          Iterator<Cell> cellItr = eachRow.cellIterator();
          int index = 1;
          while (cellItr.hasNext()) {
            Cell eachCell = cellItr.next();
            int cellType = eachCell.getCellType();
            String label = "";
            if (cellType == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
              label = eachCell.getStringCellValue();
            } else if (cellType == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
              int value = (int) eachCell.getNumericCellValue();
              label = String.valueOf(value);
            }
            builder = builder.set(index, label);
            index++;
            if (index > 10) {
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }

    }
    workbook.close();
```

Comment: Your code runs fine in my setup. Could it be `QuestionObjBuilder` that cause the problem? Try to use a simple (number only) `xlsx` file to see if there is problem.

Comment: Did you try [reading the Apache POI docs on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I did a mistake while iterating the cells. The above code runs fine for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to read all cells from the excel you can use this code,

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

        Iterator<Row> it = worksheet.rowIterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            HSSFRow r = (HSSFRow) it.next();
            Iterator<Cell> it1=r.cellIterator();
            while(it1.hasNext()){
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell)it1.next();
                System.out.println("Row: "+cell.getRowIndex()+" ,Column: "+cell.getColumnIndex());
                System.out.println(cell);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Don't use an input stream if you have a file! See the [POI docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) for why not

Comment: @Gagravarr there will be change in memory usage while using input stream instead of file.